# Why items are not being pushed in array

Tags: mongodb, express

I am using MongoseDB in order to receive some information about an item. When i try to search for it, it finds it with no trouble, but for some reasons this function is not pushing them into my array. I think this might be because of some async functions and that the console.log() is triggered before any item is being pushed in there.

```
const getOrders = function(allOrders){
    let promise = new Promise((succ, fail)=>{
        let ordersTodisplay = []
        for (let order of allOrders) {
            if (!(order.orderId === null || order.orderItem === null)){
                postMong.findById(order.orderItem, function (err, item) {
                    ordersTodisplay.push(item) 
                })
            }  
        } 
        if(ordersTodisplay.length > 0){
            succ(ordersTodisplay)    
        } else{
            fail("no items")
        }
    })
    return promise
}
router.get('/accountpage',function(req,res){ 
    const userDB = req.session.username
    if (userDB !== undefined && userDB){
        userForm.findOne({ username : userDB }, function (err, user) {
            const userOrders = user.userOrders;
            if (userOrders.length > 1) {
                getOrders(userOrders).then((result)=>{console.log(result)}, (fail)=>{console.log(fail)})
                res.render('../view/accountpage',{username: userDB,orders: itemsToDisplay});
            }
            else{
                res.render('../view/accountpage',{username: userDB,orders: "There are no orders"});
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
});
```

The result is : `no items`

Comment: Where is `itemsToDisplay` (that is used for rendering in the `if(userOrders.length > 1)` case) defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to for the database call to complete and then push the data in the array like this, using async-await:

```
const getOrders = function(allOrders){
    let promise = new Promise(async (succ, fail)=>{
        let ordersTodisplay = []
        for (let order of allOrders) {
            if (!(order.orderId === null || order.orderItem === null)){
                await postMong.findById(order.orderItem, function (err, item) {
                    ordersTodisplay.push(item) 
                })
            }  
        } 
        if(ordersTodisplay.length > 0){
            succ(ordersTodisplay)    
        } else{
            fail("no items")
        }
    })
    return promise
}
```

Comment: really weird, but it sometimes renders just one out of 2 items, other times it renders both

Comment: ohh, is there any noticeable pattern

Comment: no really, or maybe i just can't see it

Comment: sometimes it is like this https://prnt.sc/c7ZwMQdea7is other times like that https://prnt.sc/iE9sDjICvUUS

Comment: Is the value of `order.orderItem` same in both cases

Comment: Yes, it is actually

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite nested and that makes it hard to reason about what is happening.

To break down your code, you:

- get a single user that has several order IDs referenced
- load each order
- respond with those orders (although you return `itemsToDisplay` that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere, so I'm a bit confused)

I'd try to capture that logical pattern in the code. A good trick is returning early to make the code less nested and interdependent:

```js
router.get('/accountpage', function(req,res){ 
    const userDB = req.session.username;
    if (!userDB){
        res.redirect("/login");
        return;
    }

    loadUserOrders(userDB)
        .then(function(orders) {
            if(orders.length > 0) {
                res.render('../view/accountpage', {username: userDB,orders: orders});
                return;
            }
            // Note: consider returning just the empty array here, that already implies no orders
            res.render('../view/accountpage', {username: userDB, orders: "There are no orders"});
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            //TODO: render error -- case not covered by your code
        });
});

// Because this is an async function you can now await inside it, meaning no need for the callback syntax for mongoose
async function loadUserOrders(username) {
    const user = await userForm.findOne({ username: username });

    // Promise.all runs in parallel several promises and returns an array containing their results
    // .map here turns the list of userOrders into a list of promises getting each order
    return await Promise.all(user.userOrders.map((userOrder) => postMong.findById(userOrder.orderItem));
}
```

Notice how this code highlights that you are not explicitly handling the error case from loading orders.

You can further simplify this by using something like [express-async-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler) which will let your endpoint function be async as well:

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');

router.get('/accountpage', asyncHandler(async function(req,res){ 
    const userDB = req.session.username;
    if (!userDB){
        res.redirect("/login");
        return;
    }

    // Note: there is no try-catch around loadUserOrders right now, so errors will result in a 500 courtesy of express-async-handler -- better than before
    const orders = await loadUserOrders(userDB);
    if(orders.length > 0) {
        res.render('../view/accountpage', {username: userDB,orders: orders});
        return;
    }
    // Note: consider returning just the empty array here, that already implies no orders
    res.render('../view/accountpage', {username: userDB, orders: "There are no orders"});
}));
```

I think using async/await syntax all the way through leaves the code more consistent and easier to reason about than the mix of callbacks, `new Promise` and await that was suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72909734/1080564). In the end, the endpoint is not very complex, and I think the code can reflect that.

Comment: it now works as intended and the code looks cleaner, great knowledge!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope the reasons for my design choices are clear in my answer, so they can help you in the future :-)